# Asterisk Conference issue from Cisco Call Manager

Tags: asterisk, cucm

Cisco Call Manager connected to Asterisk Server (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz)x12, RAM 32GB. Conference app is confbridge. Voice quality is dropping after ~160 people with g729 and ~70 with ulaw. At the same time if we call from asterisk sip account (using zoiper) than voice quality is good for other participants.

What can be the issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was inside CUCM (Cisco Call Manager) it had limit in bandwidth of 20Mb/sec so we couldn't handle more people in single room.

Answer (score 0):

That is high number of channel

At that level on your host sound is became not perfect.

Zoiper have jitter buffer enabled, CCM- have no JB by default. So on zoiper you have more delay and less chance spot voice issues.

You can decrease load by mutting most of people in conference or spliting conference into two or three. However that require expert level in asterisk's dialplan.

Other posible issue - bandwidth. G711u(ulaw) use more bandwidth if compare with g729

Comment: It happens even all participants except admin are entering muted. What do you mean by "splitting conference" ? Jitter buffer is not enabled in asterisk

Comment: You can split conference into two rooms. Connect room using special room2room call. Anyway you need check bandwidth, load, platform stability etc. If you expect use more then 50people rooms, you need expert.

Comment: Note,that load issues can be on CCM side. Same with badnwidth and jitterbuffer

Comment: bandwidth, load, platform stability are enough about 10%-20% on asterisk server and what can be the issue in CCM and how to check ?

Comment: Sorry, on this site i can give you thoughts. I already give you enought ideas. I have no idea how YOU have check that on CCM. I am asterisk expert,not CUCM one.

Answer (score 0):

Try set individual Location parameter for asterisk trunk and set unlimited bandwidth to it.